# Create a Formula field on Lead with converted Account Details

Tags: reporting, formula-field, custom-reports, report-formula

In our organization a sale is considered as complete only when a custom picklist called Account status is changed to 'Registered' on an Account. (We deal with registering new companies)

Business would like a report which shows how many Leads that got converted eventually became a 'Registered' Account.

For this I need to create a formula field on Lead with logic
1) If Lead is not converted, VALUE = Status of Lead
2) If Lead is converted and account is registered, VALUE = ConvertedAccount.Account_Status__c

But I am unable to reference convertedAccount fields on the New Formula Field page,
[image: Error]

However, I am able to query this info from Developer Console by referencing convertedAccount.Account_Status__c

Is there any way can I make a formula to combine data from Lead and converted Account to display on a Lead Report?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can create this formula field (I tried it but didn't suceed). What I did instead was create such formula directly on a report.

1. Create a Custom Report of Leads or edit an existing one.
2. Click on Edit in the `Fields Available for Reports` section
3. Click on `Add fields related via lookup »` on the right.
4. Find `Converted Account` and add your desired field.
5. Create the report with this type. Your field should be available in the report.
6. Create a new Row Level Formula
7. Make sure to use `TEXT()` with the picklist values or else you will get errors.

Your Row Level Formula should look something like this: `TEXT(Lead.ConvertedAccount.Account_Status__c)`

Comment: Hi Ruiter, Can this work where I run a report on Leads, because I want to display leads that are not yet converted along with already converted Leads in my report.

Comment: Hi @AsifMuhammad. I updated my answer, as you don't need to add the relationship between Lead and Account. Adding the related field to the custom Lead report layout should be enough.